# New value is copied to the whole column

Tags: python, list

First of all, I think **this is not a variable address copying issue**. I have this code :

```
x = [1, 1, 0, 0]
b_u = [[0.2 for _ in range(3)]] * 4
for i in range(4):
    # The problem is on line below. This line copying new value to the whole column.
    b_u[i][0] = (2 * x[i]) / (1 + sum(x))
print(b_u)
```

And you can see whats happening in lines below :

```
# b_u :
# Before loop : [[0.2, 0.2, 0.2], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]]
# Expected : [[0.67, 0.2, 0.2], [0.67, 0.2, 0.2], [0, 0.2, 0.2], [0, 0.2, 0.2]]
# After loop : [[0.0, 0.2, 0.2], [0.0, 0.2, 0.2], [0.0, 0.2, 0.2], [0.0, 0.2, 0.2]]
```

Where am I mistaken? Is it a typo?

Comment: Don't use `*` on lists unless the contents of the list are immutable, or this behavior is wanted.

Comment: Yes... Thank you. I didn't know what can be the name of this issue? TNX anyway.

Comment: I don't know a succinct name for it, but it's saving and using multiple references to the same object instead of having multiple references to multiple objects.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Maybe "reference copying instead of value copying"? Still not super succinct though.

Comment: @wjandrea Ya, the reference/value differentiation is probably as good as it gets.